# Why numeric type is returned as 0 in python recursion code?

Tags: python, list, recursion, integer

Here is a standard `dfs` recursion code implemented in python to find the total number of paths that meet the certain condition. However the problem is it returns `0` even though the value was assigned to the variable `res`. Tried to declare the varibale as `nonlocal` and `global` before passing into the `function`, but stil wasn't working.

```py
def dfs(root, res, curSum, sum):
            
            if not root:
                 return res
            
            # print 'curSum', str(curSum)
            print 'root', str(root.val)
            print 'curSum+', str(curSum + root.val)
            print 'sumNeed', str(sum)
            
            if curSum + root.val == sum:
                    res+=1
                    print '----inner res----', str(res)
                    
            print '---outer res---', str(res)
                        
            if root.left:
                left = dfs1(root.left, res, curSum + root.val, sum)
                
            if root.right:             
                right = dfs1(root.right, res, curSum + root.val, sum)
            
            print '-----final Res------', str(res)
            return res
```

output

```
root 10
curSum+ 10
sumNeed 7
---outer res--- 0
root 5
curSum+ 15
sumNeed 7
---outer res--- 0
root 3
curSum+ 18
sumNeed 7
---outer res--- 0
root 3
curSum+ 21
sumNeed 7
---outer res--- 0
-----final Res------ 0
root -2
curSum+ 16
sumNeed 7
---outer res--- 0
-----final Res------ 0
-----final Res------ 0
root 2
curSum+ 17
sumNeed 7
---outer res--- 0
root 1
curSum+ 18
sumNeed 7
---outer res--- 0
-----final Res------ 0
-----final Res------ 0
-----final Res------ 0
root -3
curSum+ 7
sumNeed 7
----inner res---- 1
---outer res--- 1
root 11
curSum+ 18
sumNeed 7
---outer res--- 1
-----final Res------ 1
-----final Res------ 1
-----final Res------ 0
```

Looking at the output: the questions are :

1. why at the last call stack return, the `res` variable's value was reset back to 0?
2. when set the `res` variable to a list `[]` and append value to `res` by `res.append(root.val)`, then pass `res` into the `recursion`, this successfully returns a `list` with eligible values. Why this is not the case when modifying  `integer` type?

Comment: It's not *reset*, it was never changed from zero in the first place. You are returning the value of the *local* variable `rest` at each step of the recursion, captured in the assignments to `left` and `right`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You weren't using 'left' or 'right' variables for anything. That is, even when root.right and root.left weren't None, res wasn't being updated since 'left'/'right' was never returned.
2. This is a scoping issue. You can append a number to a list in recursion and that will take effect globally (i.e., not just current scope) since appending a number is not mutating the list - this is not the case with integer data type. When it comes to integers, the changes you make will only take effect for that scope only.

```
def dfs(root, res, curSum, sum):    
            
    if not root:
         return res

    # print 'curSum', str(curSum)
    print 'root', str(root.val)
    print 'curSum+', str(curSum + root.val)
    print 'sumNeed', str(sum)

    if curSum + root.val == sum:
        res+=1
        print '----inner res----', str(res)
            
    print '---outer res---', str(res)

    left = right = 0
                
    if root.left:
        left = dfs(root.left, res, curSum + root.val, sum)
        
    if root.right:             
        right = dfs(root.right, res, curSum + root.val, sum)

    print '-----final Res------', str(res)
    if root.left or root.right:
        return left + right
        
    return res
```

Comment: @Gary Bao Yutong 鲍昱彤 - if you could please give me any feedback/upvotes, that would be hugely appreciated. Thank you :-)

Comment: @lssei I did upvote as your answer was very well explained and intuitive. But someone very mean downvoted your answer, just as my question was downvoted. That's why it's showing a 0 now.

Comment: @GaryBaoYutong鲍昱彤 - thank you very much for your feedback mate, not a problem at all! I've just upvoted your question! :-)